# Is there any faster way to install TeXlive on Windows

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I recently tried to introduce some fellow students to Latex. I myself used it on linux (ubuntu), and texlive installation trough apt takes about ~2 minutes. As it turns out installation of TeXlive took about 3 hours with decent internet connection on Windows.

I don't think that it's very good look for latex to take that long to install. You can be doing stuff faster with university 365 license, especially since latex has some learning curve on top of that.

Is there any faster way to install TeXLive on Windows?

Comment: I would add that i installed texlive on ubuntu in WSL and it was faster than installing texlive with installer, but It didn't work with latex-workshop in vscode so i gave up, as i would have to figure out way to compile latex in some other way.

Comment: You can install a smaller scheme instead of default `scheme-full`. You can first download TeX Live repository to a local (or network) device and then install from that local repository. You can use a SSD instead of a HDD … BTW: Last time I've installed TeX Live on a virtual Windows via internet it took less than an hour not about three. Maybe you've used a slow mirror.

Comment: It also depends on how aggressive the Windows PCs anti virus is. A full LaTeX installation including sources and documentation are a lot of files that are downloaded one at a time. If the antivirus has to scan each downloaded file, then installation is going to take a while.

Comment: also you could start with overleaf  which is an online zero-install full texlive system

Comment: There is also [MikTeX portable](https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition) for Windows, not sure how easy it is to get all packages with that (but MikTeX does offer on-the-fly package install when you try to compile a document that uses a package that is not installed yet) but installation is fast because there is no installation :)